# How Dynamically populate the DropDown from the data uploaded through Plotly Dash dcc upload option

Tags: plotly-dash

I have uploaded the data using Plotly Dash dcc upload option. I am not able to dynamically populated the unique columns of uploaded dataframe as part of DropDown

I am able to successfuly upload the file using dcc upload option; i am able to see the output in dash table. but using same input, i am not able to see the output from dropdown.

the dataframe, i have uploaded with the columns of (country, continent, population)

i should able to get the unique columns dropdown

this is my code:

```
import base64
import datetime
import io
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_table
import dash_table_experiments as dte
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([

html.Div([
dcc.Upload(
    id='upload-data',
    children=html.Div([
        'Drag and Drop or ',
        html.A('Select Files')
    ]),
  multiple=True
),

html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
])


    dcc.Tab(label='Discrete Info', children=[
        html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
        id='select_column',
     ),
                ]),
        html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
        id='bar1',
        hoverData={'points': [{'customdata': ''}]},

        )
], style={'width': '100%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding': '0 10'}),



    ]),


])


def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):
content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
try:
    if 'csv' in filename:
        # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
        df = pd.read_csv(
            io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
    elif 'xls' in filename:
        # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
        df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

    return html.Div([
        'There was an error processing this file.'
    ])


return html.Div([
    html.H5(filename),
    html.H6(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)),

    dash_table.DataTable(
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns]
    ),

    html.Hr(),  # horizontal line

    # For debugging, display the raw contents provided by the web browser
    html.Div('Raw Content'),
    html.Pre(contents[0:200] + '...', style={
        'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap',
        'wordBreak': 'break-all'

    })
])


@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
          [Input('upload-data', 'contents')],
          [State('upload-data', 'filename'),
           State('upload-data', 'last_modified')])


def update_output (list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
if list_of_contents is not None:

    children = [
        parse_contents(c, n, d) for c, n, d in
        zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]

    return children

@app.callback(Output('select_column', 'options'
          [Input('output-data-upload', 'children'')]



def dd_update (options)

return(options)
```

Comment: Please add a minimal viable code example, including the data, that you want to visualize. Otherwise it is damn hard to assist you and follow your logic.

Comment: hi, thank you. i have included the sample code

Answer (score 1):

This is a little tricky without specific code to reference, but the basic idea is to set up a callback that will update the `options` prop of your `dcc.Dropdown`. You can have that callback triggered (`Input`) by the upload, make it read in the dataframe, obtain the columns, and then output the properly formatted list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Please use a following simple example that solves your problem

```
import base64
import io

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
    ),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown',
        options=[],
        value=None),
])

def parse_data(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV or TXT file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
        elif 'txt' or 'tsv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user upl, delimiter = r'\s+'oaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')), delimiter = r'\s+')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])

    return df

@app.callback(
    Output('dropdown', 'options'),
    [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
     Input('upload-data', 'filename')])
def update_options(contents, filename):
    if contents:
        df = parse_data(contents, filename)
        df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])
        lst = [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.columns]
        return lst
    else:
        return []


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code, very basic, that you can use as a reference

```
html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(children=[
      dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown_students_cols', options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in list(filter(lambda x: x!='userid', list(df)))], value='component'),
    ]),
    html.Div(children=[
      dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown_row_names'),
    ]),
])

@app.callback(
  Output(component_id='dropdown_row_names', component_property='options'),
  [Input(component_id='dropdown_students_cols', component_property='value')],)
def get_row_names(column_name='component'):
  row_names = df[column_name].unique().tolist()
  lst = [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in row_names]
  print(lst)
  return lst
```

The print statement in the callback returns a list of dictionaries that I can use for options:

```
[{'label': 'mod_glossary', 'value': 'mod_glossary'}, {'label': 'mod_quiz', 'value': 'mod_quiz'},...]
```

1. Don't pay attention to lambda function in the original dropdown `id='dropdown_students_cols'`, I just needed to exclude this column from selection.
2. When you make selection in the original dropdown `id='dropdown_students_cols'`, it invokes the callback function with the selection as an argument.
3. This selection gives me a required column in the df and then I build a list of unique rows in this column.
4. Then I iterate over this list to build a list of dictionaries with `label:value`
5. The print statement confirms that the list is built successfully
6. Then I return that list as options for the child dropdown `id='dropdown_row_names'`

So you can use another trigger as Input, in your case Upload, pass values into the callback, process the data as you need and then return a list if dictionaries as options for the dropdown.

I suggest you trim your code to a vary basic working example and then slowly build up from it.